# How to use initialized variable in one cell in another

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

This is one cell

---

```
def compute_abs_difference_matrix(Y):

n_samples = Y.shape[0]

# compute the absolute difference matrix

# and remember to return the matrix
# INSERT YOUR CODE HERE

for i in range(n_samples):
    for j in range(n_samples):
        abs_difference_matrix[i, j] = abs(Y[i] - Y[j])

return abs_difference_matrix
```

---

This is the next cell

```
abs_difference_matrix = compute_abs_difference_matrix(Y_pred)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

ax.set_title("Absolute difference matrix for Y_pred")

cax = ax.imshow(abs_difference_matrix)

cbar = fig.colorbar(cax)
```

---

but I'm getting this error "name 'abs_difference_matrix' is not defined" how do I fix this, ive already initialized this in the cell above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize an empty array for `abs_difference_matrix`

```
def compute_abs_difference_matrix(Y):
    abs_difference_matrix = np.array([])
    n_samples = Y.shape[0]

    # compute the absolute difference matrix

    # and remember to return the matrix
    # INSERT YOUR CODE HERE

    for i in range(n_samples):
        for j in range(n_samples):
            abs_difference_matrix[i, j] = abs(Y[i] - Y[j])

    return abs_difference_matrix
```

Comment: i tried this answer, but got another error saying "too many indices for array" - so far i learned this is because the array is not in the dimension that's required, but dont know how to fix